# powershell and method/property exceptions in excel automation

Tags: vba, excel, powershell

Not able to use, methods and properties, of Excel VBA, in PowerShell code.

I tried, some modification, but couldn't call PasteSpecial Method properly from Power Shell. Also, I am using MS-Office 2010, and Power Shell

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1  


# edit formula and fill down
$objSheet.Range("B1").Value2 = 2
$objSheet.Range("C1").Value2 = 5
$objSheet.Range("A1").Activate()
$objSheet.Range("A1").Select()
$objSheet.Range("A1").Formula = '=SUM(B1:C1)'
$objSheet.Range("A1").Copy
[void] $objSheet.Range("A2").Activate()
$objRange = $objSheet.Range("A2:A10")
[void] $objRange.PasteSpecial(-4123,-4142)
```

Error :

```
Exception calling "PasteSpecial" with "2" argument(s): "PasteSpecial method of 
Range class failed"
At C:\Users\anc92044\Desktop\shell\labs\del.ps1:36 char:30
+ [void] $objRange.PasteSpecial <<<< (-4123,-4142)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

Comment: Try without `.Value`  - `$objSheet.Cells.Item(1,3) = "Hi"`

Comment: Thanks! But this seems, only temporary solution, which worked only in one case. What if I want to work with other properties like, formula, font, comment etc. I am not able to determine the problem behind this.

Comment: According to this link there shouldn't be any problem with that: http://learn-powershell.net/2012/12/20/powershell-and-excel-adding-some-formatting-to-your-report/

Comment: Right! I checked similar blogs, and forums for the above issue, but none of the solution worked. And I am still reading more about Use-Culture.

Comment: This is .NET, it uses COM objects, not excel-vba. not sure what you are expecting `$objExcel.DoEvents` to do, but its not a legitimate property, method, or otherwise of the excel com object. You'll have a lot easier time if you stop trying to think in terms of vba and just start anew with a powershell tutorial, there's many out there. Also, a call to sleep is never necessary, and Tim is right, you shouldn't be calling `.Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem here is that you aren't familiar with PowerShell more than anything I think. Take some time to read up on it and get familiar with the context of the language. That will help more than anything I think.

So, if you were to type `$objExcel | Get-Member` you would see that `ActiveCell` is a property. That should be fairly self explanatory for you... that property is the currently active cell for the active worksheet in the active workbook. If you do `$objExcel.ActiveCell | Get-Member` you would see that `Value2` is a property of the active cell. If you now do `$objExcel.ActiveCell.Value2 = "Hi"` the currently active cell in Excel will now have the text "Hi" in it. Why `Value2` and not `Value`? Well, `Value` is already a method, so the property of the cell that contains its "Value" was moved to `Value2`. I think that's confusing, but I don't make the rules, I just play the game.

Not everything is quite that intuitive, but with a little bit of trial and error you can get around fairly easily. You're probably going to want to get familiar with piping things to Get-Member, and you do not need to preface it with write-output. If you had done a `$objSheet | Get-Member` you would see Range listed there. (ok, GM is short for Get-Member, so going forward I'm using that alias, I'm tired of writing Get-Member)

```
Range                             ParameterizedProperty Range Range (Variant, Variant) {get}
```

What that should tell you is

- the Name "Range"
- what it is, a ParameterizedProperty
- The last section is a bit tougher, since it includes several things. The first is the kind of object that item contains, it is a Range object, which doesn't really tell us much. Then it has the usage for it Range(Variant, Variant). Lastly it tells us if we can get, set, or both. It's set to {get}, which kind of makes sense since we aren't setting anything, we're just getting info from Excel to work with, what we would be setting comes as properties of the range object.

Ok,`$objRange = $objSheet.Range("A1","A1")` is what you probably wanted in your script. A range can include several cells so you have to give it a starting point and a stopping point, even if they're the same point. From that you could do the `$objRange | GM` that you had attempted before, and not get an error (no need for write-output, as I mentioned before). Then you can use either the `Select()` or `Activate()` method to make that the active cell(s) in Excel, and can use `$objExcel.ActiveCell` as mentioned before, or you can do most anything with `$objRange` directly that you could do with `$objExcel.ActiveCell` without having to make that the active cell(s).

I hope this helps to clear a few things up for you.

**Edit:** Ok, you've definitely tried many things, but looks like you still can't quite grasp some of the concepts.

If you are going to call a method, then (so far as I can think of) you will need the method's parameters to be in parenthesis (like how you have called the Range method). So, for Range.PasteSpecial you need to enclose the parameters in (). To find out what they should be I did a quick look on Google and searched for "excel comobject pastespecial" and was rewarded with the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476%28v=office.15%29.aspx) for it. On that page I see that the 4 parameters are all optional, but chances are you are going to want to at least include the XLPasteType. There's a link to the XLPasteType option from that page, and it lists both Name and Value for each one. To me that says that if one doesn't work, try the other. I could not get xlPasteFormulas to work for me, but I was able to get -4123 to work (the Value listed for xlPasteFormulas). Same thing went for the next parameter xlPasteSpecialOperation of xlPasteSpecialOperationName and -4142. What I ended up with was this:

```
$objRange.PasteSpecial(-4123,-4142)
```

That came back in PowerShell with True, and in Excel it pasted as expected (my copied cell of `H1` containing the formula `=SUM(H2:H4)` was pasted into my `$objRange` of `A1` as the formula `=SUM(A2:A4)`. Now, you could add `[Void]` before it in Powershell to suppress the True response with no harm if you want.

Also, this is not VBA. All you are going to do is confuse people by calling it that. This is PowerShell. It is a .Net scripting language, and not Visual Basic based like VBA is.

Comment: Hi, your answer gave some insight into Power Shell function parameters. As per your suggestion, I tried every possible combination, but failed to call a VBA method. I have edited original question with more info. Thanks!

Comment: Kindly see the edit in question, I also did, what you said, but couldn't get success with PasteSpecial Method using Powershell.

Comment: You got an error before the PasteSpecial line. Your Copy line is missing the () at the end. Change it to `$objSheet.Range("A1").Copy()` and see if that fixes things. Right now you are trying to paste when you have nothing copied. With that change I was able to run your code above without errors.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was so absorbed with PasteSpecial method, that I did not pay attention to Copy method, and made mistake in writing. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The bloggers above helped, I hope this offers a complete testable solution.
In keeping with the copy-paste described above as the problem, 
I was able to take the advice above and copy a formula to a range and the 
formula then calculated as desired.  The whole idea is,

1. Open a CSV file as text in every column so as not to lose YYYY-MM-DD and HH:MM:SS date-time formats, and to have columns keep leading zeros where desired.
2. Insert some columns.
3. Insert a formula.
4. Copy the formula onto a range thus showing the new values.
5. Copy just the values to another cell.
6. Close the sheet, workbook, and excel.

**Suggested Example Data is a ASCII TXT CSV file named c:\temp\input.txt.csv**

```
"Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4_is_a_string_of_at_least_32_characters"
"Row2","R2C2","R2C3","R2C4_is_a_string_leadz_0234_XYZ.zip"
"row3","r3c2","r3c3","r3c4_keep_leading_zero_0000_XYZ.zip"
```

**Code**

```
function Release-Ref ($ref) { 
([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$ref) -gt 0) 
[System.GC]::Collect() 
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers() 
} 

### Set input and output path
$inputCSV        = "C:\temp\input.txt.csv"
$outputXLSX_xlsx = "C:\temp\output.xlsx"

### Create a new Excel Workbook with one empty sheet
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add(1)
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item(1)

### Build the QueryTables.Add command
### QueryTables does the same as when clicking "Data » From Text" in Excel
$TxtConnector = ("TEXT;" + $inputCSV)
$Connector = $worksheet.QueryTables.add($TxtConnector,$worksheet.Range("A1"))
$query = $worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name)

### Set the delimiter (, or ;) according to your regional settings
$query.TextFileOtherDelimiter = $Excel.Application.International(5)

### Set the format to delimited and text for every column
### A trick to create an array of 2s is used with the preceding comma
$query.TextFileParseType  = 1
$query.TextFileColumnDataTypes = ,2 * $worksheet.Cells.Columns.Count
$query.AdjustColumnWidth = 1

### Execute & delete the import query
$query.Refresh()
$query.Delete()

### 
$xlShiftToRight = -4161

#$eCol=$worksheet.cells.item(1,4).entireCol
$eCol=$worksheet.Range("D1").EntireColumn
[void] $eCol.Insert($xlShiftToRight)

$eCol=$worksheet.Range("D1").EntireColumn
[void] $eCol.Insert($xlShiftToRight)

$eCol=$worksheet.Range("D1").EntireColumn
$eCol.NumberFormat = "General"

$eCol=$worksheet.Range("E1").EntireColumn
$eCol.NumberFormat = "General"

<# Get the number of rows and columns in the "Used Range" #>
$objRange=$worksheet.UsedRange
$rows=$objRange.Rows.Count
$cols=$objRange.Columns.Count

<# After inserting new columns, label the columns with headers and 
## insert a formula to copy substring from cells to the right #>
$worksheet.Range("D1","D1").Value2 = "Ship"
$formula_ship = "=MID(RC[2],24,4)"
$worksheet.Cells.Item(2,4).Formula = "=MID(RC[2],24,4)"

$worksheet.Range("E1","E1").Value2 = "Station"
$formula_station = "=MID(RC[1],29,3)"
$worksheet.Cells.Item(2,5).Formula = "=MID(RC[1],29,3)"

## Copy the formula from D2:E2 to D3:E<rows> ##
[void] $worksheet.Range("D2","E2").Copy()
$paste_alpha="D3"
$paste_omega="E"+$rows.ToString()
$objRange=$worksheet.Range($paste_alpha,$paste_omega)
[void] $objRange.PasteSpecial(-4123)

## Copy the values calculated by the formula ##
$copy_alpha="D1"
$copy_omega="E"+$rows.ToString()
[void] $worksheet.Range($copy_alpha,$copy_omega).Copy()
$paste_alpha="H1"
$paste_omega="I"+$rows.ToString()
$objRange=$worksheet.Range($paste_alpha,$paste_omega)
[void] $objRange.PasteSpecial(-4163)

## Ensure the ship number format has leading zeros ##
$eCol=$worksheet.Range("D1").EntireColumn
$eCol.NumberFormat = "0000"

### Save & close the Workbook as XLSX.  This may seem like overkill but without something kept a lock on the xlsx file.
$Workbook.SaveAs($outputXLSX_xlsx,51)
$excel.Application.Quit()
$a = Release-Ref($worksheet)
$a = Release-Ref($workbook)
$a = Release-Ref($excel)
```